# Custom Acknowledgement for Incoming Messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

Our orchestration looks like this:

```
ReceiveOrder
TryScope (Long Running)
   AcknowledgementScope (Atomic)
     ConstructOrderAckMessage
        TransformOrderToAck (using a map)
     SendOrderAckToMessageQueue
   AtomicWebServiceScope
      ImportOrderToDBExpression
   Construct and send message to another process
CatchException
      ConstructErrorExpression
      HandleExceptionStartOrchestration
```

When we tested this with about 6000 orders, we noticed that all of them resulted in an acknowledgment message (`SendOrderAckToMessageQueue`). The acknowledgment is a simple XML based on a schema provided by the crew that sends the order to this orchestration.

However, not all of them got imported into the database (`ImportOrderToDBExpression`) (about 45). In fact, there are no errors or failures or suspended instances of any kind. There's nothing unusual about the orders that did not get imported. If it failed, it did so silently.

Please note, that the `AcknowledgementScope` portion is something added recently; prior to that all the orders got imported successfully.

Is this because I have the Scope set incorrectly in this orchestration? Where else could the problem be? Is there a better way to send acknowledgment in a fool proof way? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How is the InportOderToDBExpression done?   Is this through a send port or are you doing something in code?

Comment: Also you appear to be sending the Ack Message before you do the insert.  Also why are you using Atomic scopes?

Comment: Thank you @Dijkgraaf The importOrder is done using an SP invoked from a .DLL referenced by the BizTalk application project. No send port involved. It is all done via code in that expression. 

The requirement was to send acknowledgment as soon as the incoming message is received. 

No specific reason for atomic scope.

Comment: It is rather bad practice to send messages by calling a DLL as you run into issue with both multi-threading and error handling.   If that referenced DLL is not written to handle either of those correctly, you will get your exact situation and not see any errors as they aren't being bubbled back up too BizTalk.  I would advise using a send port and the correct adapter to connect, as it has those capabilities built in.  Your DLL may be trying to log errors to the Event Log, but it may not have permissions and hence even that is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention any Catch Blocks. Do you have Catch Blocks on all your Scopes?

If there is an Exception without a Catch Block or a Catch Block that does not log the Exception, it will appear to silently fail.

Comment: Thanks @Johns-305 I do not have catch block for all my Scopes. There is only one Catch Exception at the bottom of the orchestration.

Comment: Ok, unless you're logging the error there, you won't see anything.

Comment: Thanks @Johns-305 the errors are logged into the event log, as well as to written to a table in the DB; I just could not find any failures logged in either of those places.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main thing you are doing wrong is calling an external DLL to insert records into a database.

Unless that DLL is very well written to be multi-threading capable including limiting the number of concurrent connections and has good retry and error handling capabilities then it can encounter an error and silently fail.

Even if you do have errors being logged in the DLL to the Event Log, you then have to give permissions for the Application name that the DLL uses to write to the event logs, otherwise the DLL will fail in it's catch blocks trying to write to the event log.

What you should be doing is using a Send Port with the appropriate Adapter to send records to the database.

Also there are very few situations in which you need an atomic scope.  With an atomic scope it is up to the developer to implement any rollback.  Also you probably do not need a long running scope unless you expect your Orchestration to take a long while and that is should dehydrate while waiting for a response.

Sending the Acknowledgement after the BizTalk Orchestration has received the message is fine, as long as you can then somehow resume a failed message in BizTalk, so you need to have some sort of retry mechanism.